# IK rig seems to be "popping."

Tags: animation, rigging, unity

This is my first time setting up an IK rig and after exporting it to Unity, I wanted to see how it looked like. The movement was ok, but it has this weird pop effect that I have no idea how to get rid of.

[Example here](https://gyazo.com/72b30022733ecb4d41bf548c7395e964)

I'd appreciate any help or advice given, thank you.

Comment: It looks like your IK target is moving too far from the hip joint, so the leg rapidly becomes fully extended in order to try to reach it.

Comment: Yup, it seems like that was the problem here. Thank Will Chen.